# Generating a probability distribution with desired std.dev

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'd like to generate a list of numbers for a size $n$ s.t their sum 1 and the sample std.variation is some fixed number $\sigma$. How can I do it ?

Comment: Do you mean by hand, or using a software package like MATLAB, Mathematica, or R?

Comment: With a software package.

Comment: If their sum has to be 1, then their mean has to be $\frac 1n$

Comment: Yes :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n > 1$ be fixed.

Choose an arithmetic progression of $n$ terms, centered at ${\large{\frac{1}{n}}}$ (i.e., with mean ${\large{\frac{1}{n}}}$).

Leaving the common difference $d$ unknown, compute the sample standard deviation as a function of $d$, set it equal to the target sample standard deviation, and solve for $d$.

Explicitly, define $x_1,...,x_n$ by
$$x_k = \frac{1}{n}+d\left(k-\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$$
with $d$ assumed nonnegative, but otherwise left unknown.

Let $s$ be the target sample standard deviation.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;s^2 &=
\sum_{k=1}^n 
\frac
{\left(x_k - \frac{1}{n}\right)^2}
{n}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{d^2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k-\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2\\[4pt]
&=\frac{d^2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k^2-k(n+1) + \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{d^2}{n}
\left(
\left(
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2
\right) 
- 
\left(
(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n k
\right)
+  
\left(
\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}
\sum_{k=1}^n 1
\right)
\right)
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{d^2}{n}
\left(
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
- 
(n+1)\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)
+  
\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\right)
n
\right)
\\[4pt]
&=
d^2\left(\frac{n^2-1}{12}\right)\\[10pt]
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{hence}\\[10pt]
d &=2s\sqrt{\frac{3}{n^2-1}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
So that's one way.

Here's another way, similar in spirit, but algebraically a lot simpler . . .

Let $n > 1$ be fixed.

Define $x_1,...,x_n$ by
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 = \frac{1}{n}- d\\[4pt]
x_k = \frac{1}{n}&\text{if}\;\,1 < k < n\\[4pt]
x_n = \frac{1}{n}+ d\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
with $d$ assumed nonnegative, but otherwise left unknown.

In other words, set all terms equal to the mean except the first and last terms, which are to be placed symmetrically opposite from the mean, at a distance $d$, yet to be determined.

Let $s$ be the target sample standard deviation.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;s^2 &=\frac{2d^2}{n}\\[10pt]
\text{hence}\;\;d &=s\sqrt{{\small{\frac{n}{2}}}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Here's still another, more general way . . .

Assuming the target standard deviation $s$ is positive, fix $n > 1$, and choose $n$ real numbers $w_1,...,w_n$, not all equal, but otherwise arbitrary.

For the sample $w_1,...,w_n$, compute the sample mean $\mu_0$, and the sample standard deviation $\sigma_0$.

Then, letting $x_1,...,x_n$ be given by 
$$x_k = s\left(\frac{w_k - \mu_0}{\sigma_0}\right)+\frac{1}{n}$$
for $k = 1,...,n$, it follows that the values $x_1,...,x_n$ have sample mean ${\large{\frac{1}{n}}}$ and sample standard deviation $s$.

If instead you want $n$ *random* values, you can use a pseudo-random number generator to generate $n$ random numbers $w_1,...,w_n$ from a known distribution, with mean $\mu_0$, say, and standard deviation $\sigma_0$, say.

Then, letting $x_1,...,x_n$ be given by 
$$x_k = \sigma\left(\frac{w_k - \mu_0}{\sigma_0}\right)+\frac{1}{n}$$
for $k = 1,...,n$, you get $n$ pseudo-random numbers $x_1,...,x_n$ from a distribution with mean ${\large{\frac{1}{n}}}$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

Comment: So you are saying that the geometric progession of $n $ terms you give above, if we use that $d $, has the std deviation wanted?

Comment: Yes, assuming no algebraic errors in the simplification.

Comment: sure; clever solution

Comment: @RGS:  Note: it's an arithmetic progression, not a geometric progression.

Comment: yes, I had noticed it in the time being. While these $n $ values have desired mean and std deviation, they are deterministic. I wonder if the OP didn't want a way to generate a set of random values that followed a distribution with mean $1/n $ and fixed std deviation...

Comment: @RGS: I edited my answer to allow for random numbers.

Comment: I wanted to give another +1 :p

Comment: Haha, but thanks for the moral support.